# "Install additional required components" when switching between Xcode 10 and 11 beta

Tags: xcode, xcode10, xcode11

I often have to switch between Xcode 10.2.1 and Xcode 11.0 beta 2.
Most of the times there is this popup saying *Install additional required components*.

In the past I always used `sudo xcode-select -s <pathToXcodeVersion>` to switch between Xcode versions, which prevented this popup to show.
But this doesn't work, or mostly doesn't work. I have to install those components to get the Xcode version running.

Also it doesn't matter if I switch from Xcode 10.2.1 to 11.0b2 or vice versa.

I'm running macOS 10.14.5.

Anyone having the same problem? And perhaps a solution?

---

**Update: Still not fixed in Beta 5**

---

**Update 2: Switching between Xcode 11 and other versions works now without showing this dialog**

Comment: Same as me. It seem a bug of apple.

Comment: How about setting the command line tools version explicitly for both versions? Xcode > Preferences > Locations

Comment: Tried that too @Desdenova

Comment: In my experience, this is the UI for the `xcode-select` command. So there can only be one active selection.

Comment: You are probably right. Following this document seems like multiple versions use single command line tools. https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2339/_index.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I got it now:

When I want to switch Xcode versions, **in the currently opened version** I go to Settings > Locations and set the Command Line Tools version that I want to switch to.

Then I close Xcode and open the just selected Xcode version.

I tested this now a few times switching from Xcode 10.2.1 and 11.0 Beta 5.

Answer (score 1):

You can try command to prevent install Component again in future `/Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode -installComponents`. I just try 1 minute ago.

Comment: It kinda works for an hour where I can switch a few times without being asked, but then the popup is there again. Hope it will be fixed with v11.0b3